# Spark 2 application failed with Couldn't find leader offsets for Error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have my spark applciation reading data from Kafka and ingesting into Kudu. It has run successfully for almost 25hrs and ingested data into Kudu. After that, I see new leader was elected for kafka partitions from kafka logs. My application went into FINISHED state with the following error,

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([test,0]))
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:334)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:331)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:121)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Does it mean that, whenever a new leader is elected Spark application will fail?

I have seen a lot of posts on Stackoverflow where everyone said that they are not able to launch the application with this error. But, in my case, it ran for 25hrs and then FINISHED.

Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong? I searched on Kafka issues with no luck related to this.

Comment: Whats the replication factor for partitions in your Kafka topic?

Comment: Replication factor is 3

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when the count of the topicPartition expected by the spark streaming doesn't match with the topic partition provided by simple Kafka client [Used by spark to get the topicPartition-Leader offsets].

So by the time Spark Streaming requested for the offsets, the leader for topicPartition [test, 0] was not available. Hence Spark threw the exception message. What version of Spark and Kafka are you using?

Comment: I'm using spark 2.2 and kafka 0.9. Also, as I see from the kafka logs at the time when job is finished, a new leader was elected. Spark streaming couldn't find the new leader and got failed.

Comment: Can I set this spark.streaming.kafka.maxRetries property to some value to make the driver retry connecting to Kafka so that the application wont be failed. This is a problem in production.

Comment: Yes,increasing the  spark.streaming.kafka.maxRetries will certainly help. Also increase the "refreshLeaderBackoffMs", this will increase the time between each tries. By default the "refreshLeaderBackoffMs" is 200 ms and number of retries is 1.